# Observium can't resolve host, but I can ping it

Tags: snmp, observium

```
./add_device.php 1.2.3.4 catalyst v1
```

fails with

```
Try to add 1.2.3.4:
Could not resolve 1.2.3.4.
Devices failed: 1.
```

but ping works

```
fping 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4. is alive
```

but snmpwalk works like:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c catalyst 1.2.3.4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst...
...
```

web interface add device also fails same way.
what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The community edition can't resolve IP's (go figure), so you have to create an entry in /etc/hosts for your IP and assign somename.whatever to it and then use that hostname and it will work.

Comment: you save my day :D